# Regex to remove text before "http://"?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a ruby app parsing a bunch of URLs from strings:

```
@text = "a string with a url http://example.com"

@text.split.grep(/http[s]?:\/\/\w/)

@text[0] = "http://example.com"
```

This works fine ^^

But sometimes the URLs have text before the HTTP:// for example

```
@text = "What's a spacebar? ...http://example.com"

@text[0] = "...http://example.com"
```

Is there a regex that can select just the text before "http://" in a string so I can strip it out?

Comment: Heads up, you are going to have the same issue at the end of the URL too, and that will be much tougher to deal with.

Comment: Yes, I agree with JohnFx. Regex arent' that great for this problem. Matching URLs in strings has been asked on SO before. Have a look and see what solutions they used -- ie what libraries etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spliting and then grepping is an odd way to do this.  Why don't you just use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812):

```
@text = "a string with a url http://example.com"
urls = @text.scan(/http[s]?:\/\/\S+/)
url[0]  # => "http://example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem - it ignores everything preceding the matching text.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps a nicer way to achieve the same result is to use the URI standard library.

```
require 'uri'
text = "a string with a url http://example.com and another URL here:http://2.example.com and this here"
URI.extract(text, ['http', 'https'])
# => ["http://example.com", "http://2.example.com"]
```

Documentation: [URI.extract](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M001446)

Answer (score 1):

```
.*(?=http://)
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could combine the two.

```
.*(?=(f|ht)tp[s]://)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for http://, then remove the parts of the string before that (as the =~ returns the offset into the string)